# How can I read a continuously updating log file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a application generating logs in every 5 sec. The logs are in below format.

```
11:13:49.250,interface,0,RX,0
11:13:49.250,interface,0,TX,0
11:13:49.250,interface,1,close,0
11:13:49.250,interface,4,error,593
11:13:49.250,interface,4,idle,2994215
and so on for other interfaces...
```

I am working to convert these into below CSV format:

```
Time,interface.RX,interface.TX,interface.close....
11:13:49,0,0,0,....
```

Simple as of now but the problem is, I have to get the data in CSV format online, i.e as soon the log file updated the CSV should also be updated.

What I have tried to read the output and make the header is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use File::Tail;
my $head=["Time"];
my $pos={};
my $last_pos=0;
my $current_event=[];

my $events=[];

my $file = shift;
$file = File::Tail->new($file);

while(defined($_=$file->read)) {
     next if $_ =~ some filters;

     my ($time,$interface,$count,$eve,$value) = split /[,\n]/, $_;
     my $key = $interface.".".$eve;

     if (not defined $pos->{$eve_key}) {
          $last_pos+=1;
          $pos->{$eve_key}=$last_pos;
          push @$head,$eve;
        }
        print join(",", @$head) . "\n";
}
```

Is there any way to do this using Perl?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have? Do you maybe need to open an output file for append on every iteration of the read loop?

Comment: What's the specific problem?  Can you reduce it to just a problem with File::Tail or some other part of your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV) will allow you to both read and write CSV format files. [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV) will internally use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV_XS) if it's installed, or it will fall back to using [Text::CSV_PP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV_PP) (thanks to Brad Gilbert for improving this explanation).

Grouping the related rows together is something you will have to do; it is not clear from your example where the source date goes to.

Making sure that the CSV output is updated is primarily a question of ensuring that you have the output file line buffered.

---

As David M suggested, perhaps you should look at the [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm) module to deal with the continuous reading aspect of the problem.  That should allow you to continually read from the input log file.

You can then use the 'parse' method in Text::CSV to split up the read line, and the 'print' method to format the output.  How you combine the information from the various input lines to create an output line is a mystery to me - I cannot see how the logic works from the example you give.  However, I assume you know what you need to do, and these tools will give you the mechanisms you need to handle the data.

No-one can do much more to spoon-feed you the answer.  You are going to have to do some thinking for yourself.  You will have a file handle that can be continuously read via File::Tail; you will have a CSV structure for reading the data lines; you will probably have another CSV structure for the written output; you will have an output file handle that you ensure is flushed every time you write.  Connecting these dots is now your problem.

Comment: thanks Jonathan but my problem is how to read and convert the data continusly updating in log file. Can you please suggest me any code to do that.

Comment: @Octopus: so your problem isn't really about CSV parsing, it's about continually updating a file based on changing input? That wasn't very clear from the question.

Comment: If your problem is to continuously read a log file, you should ask that question instead of hiding behind all the CSV stuff. :)

Comment: My problem is to read the continuously updating log file and create a csv as i give in my example output.